# Replacing full method through ASM

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to write a script that replaces each method body with a basic throw new exception() line. I am in the starting steps of learning ASM so any pointers on where to look would be appreciated.

What I have done so far:

```
package methodtester;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ACC_INTERFACE;
import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ASM4;
import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ATHROW;
import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.DUP;
import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.INVOKESPECIAL;
import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.NEW;

public class MethodTransformer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = MethodTester.class.getResourceAsStream("/methodtester/testingMethod.class");

        ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(in);

        ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);

        ExceptionThrower exceptionThrower = new ExceptionThrower(classWriter);

        classReader.accept(exceptionThrower, 0);

        File outputDir = new File("build/classes/methodtester/");

        outputDir.mkdirs();

        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream =
            new DataOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(
                    new File(outputDir,"testingMethod-postASM.class")));

        dataOutputStream.write(classWriter.toByteArray());
    }

    public static class ExceptionThrower extends ClassVisitor {
        private String _className;
        private boolean _isInterface;

        public ExceptionThrower(ClassVisitor classVisitor) {
            super(ASM4, classVisitor);
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(
            int version, int access, String name, String signature,
            String superName, String[] interfaces) {

            cv.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);

            _className = name;

            _isInterface = (access & ACC_INTERFACE) != 0;
        }

        @Override
        public MethodVisitor visitMethod(
            int access, String name, String desc, String signature,
            String[] exceptions) {

            MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature,
                exceptions);

            if (!_isInterface && mv != null && !name.equals("<init>")) {
                ExceptionThrowerMethod exceptionThrowerMethod =
                    new ExceptionThrowerMethod(mv);

                return exceptionThrowerMethod;
            }

            return mv;
        }

        public static class ExceptionThrowerMethod extends MethodVisitor {
            public ExceptionThrowerMethod(MethodVisitor methodVisitor) {
                super(ASM4, methodVisitor);
            }

            @Override
            public void visitCode() {
                mv.visitCode();
                mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "java/io/IOException");
                mv.visitInsn(DUP);
                mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/io/IOException", "<init>", "()V", false);
                mv.visitInsn(ATHROW);
                mv.visitMaxs(2, 0);
                mv.visitEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far I am able to insert the throw new IOException() instructions into the beginning of the method, but this does not run at runtime as I am given this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid start_pc 8 in LocalVariableTable in class file methodtester/testingMethod
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at methodtester.MethodTester.main(MethodTester.java:27)
```

Looking at javap -c-v I get:

```
 public void testing() throws java.io.IOException;
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: new           #14                 // class java/io/IOException
         3: dup
         4: invokespecial #15                 // Method java/io/IOException."<init>":()V
         7: athrow
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            8       0     0  this   Lmethodtester/testingMethod;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 24: 8
        line 25: 8
    Exceptions:
      throws java.io.IOException
}
```

Looking at the classes with ASMifier I see that the method is:

```
mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "testing", "()V", null, null);
mv.visitCode();
mv.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "java/io/IOException");
mv.visitInsn(DUP);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/io/IOException", "<init>", "()V", false);
mv.visitInsn(ATHROW);
mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
mv.visitLdcInsn("testing method");
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
mv.visitMaxs(2, 1);
mv.visitEnd();
}
```

Looks like I need to change the LocalVariableTable to get it to start at 0 with length 0.

Thanks!

Edit: updated using COMPUTE_FRAMES and updated the new error code

Comment: The method that you want to replace has no arguments?

Comment: @saka1029 It will, but for now I am just testing on a simple method with no argument and hoping to get that to work first.

Comment: Try to change ClassWriter option `ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS` to `ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES`.  See [ClassWriter options](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf#page=50)

Comment: @saka1029 made the change and updated the question with the new error, seems like I need to somehow change the LocalVariableTable with asm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the original `MethodVisitor`, you received from the `ClassWriter`, to the super constructor of your custom `MethodVisitor`. This implies, that every `visit…` call, you didn’t override, will be delegated to that `MethodVisitor`, replicating the entire original code.

Of course, first, you don’t want to replicate the original code, second, receiving contradicting `visit…` calls on the writer *after* your invocations of `visitMaxs` and `visitEnd` does not help creating valid code.

When you want to entirely *replace* a method, you should not exhibit the target writer’s `MethodVisitor` to the base class, but use it solely for your own code generation:

```
public static class ExceptionThrowerMethod extends MethodVisitor {
    private final MethodVisitor target;

    public ExceptionThrowerMethod(MethodVisitor methodVisitor) {
        super(ASM4, null);
        this.target=methodVisitor;
    }

    @Override
    public void visitCode() {
        target.visitCode();
        target.visitTypeInsn(NEW, "java/io/IOException");
        target.visitInsn(DUP);
        target.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL,"java/io/IOException","<init>","()V",false);
        target.visitInsn(ATHROW);
        target.visitMaxs(2, 0);
        target.visitEnd();
    }
}
```

By they way, you can simplify your resource access by letting the `Class` resolve the resource locally, e.g. `testingMethod.class.getResourceAsStream("testingMethod.class")`.

Comment: Thank you, I was getting it to work by adding a boolean check to the override version of all visit* methods, it was a mess and this solution is much much cleaner!